# EF Core and derived classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have the following architecture.

Base classes:

```
public abstract class BaseDevice<TDeviceSync> : IPosition, IChainByPreviousId
    where TDeviceSync : BaseDeviceSync
{
    public virtual TDeviceSync AddedSync { get; set; }

    public virtual TDeviceSync? DeletedSync { get; set; }


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AddedSyncId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? DeletedSyncId { get; set; }
    public int? Position { get; set; }

    public int? PreviousDeviceId { get; set; }
    public virtual BaseDevice<TDeviceSync>? PreviousDevice { get; set; }

}

public abstract class BaseDeviceSync
{

    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public DateTime SyncDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseDeviceHistory<TBaseDevice, TDeviceSync> 
    where TBaseDevice : BaseDevice<TDeviceSync> 
    where TDeviceSync : BaseDeviceSync
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public virtual TBaseDevice Device { get; set; }

    public string SyncId { get; set; }
    public string OldValue { get; set; }
    public string NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

and "one group" of derived classes:

```
public class RegisteredDevice : BaseDevice<RegisteredDeviceSync>
{
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
    public string SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
    public string EldIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string? DataTransferOptions { get; set; }

    public virtual RegisteredDeviceSync AddedSync { get; set; }
    public virtual RegisteredDeviceSync? DeletedSync { get; set; }

    private ICollection<RegisteredDeviceHistory> _history;
    public virtual ICollection<RegisteredDeviceHistory> History { get => _history ??= new List<RegisteredDeviceHistory>(); protected set => _history = value; }
}

public class RegisteredDeviceHistory : BaseDeviceHistory<RegisteredDevice, RegisteredDeviceSync>
{
    public virtual RegisteredDeviceSync RegisteredDeviceSync { get; set; }
    public RegisteredDeviceFieldName FieldName { get; set; }
}

public class RegisteredDeviceSync : BaseDeviceSync
{
    private ICollection<RegisteredDeviceHistory> _history;
    public virtual ICollection<RegisteredDeviceHistory> History { get => _history ??= new List<RegisteredDeviceHistory>(); protected set => _history = value; }

    private ICollection<RegisteredDevice> _addedDevices;
    public virtual ICollection<RegisteredDevice> AddedDevices { get => _addedDevices ??= new List<RegisteredDevice>(); protected set => _addedDevices = value; }

    private ICollection<RegisteredDevice> _deletedDevices;
    public virtual ICollection<RegisteredDevice> DeletedDevices { get => _deletedDevices ??= new List<RegisteredDevice>(); protected set => _deletedDevices = value; }
}
```

(I have also more "groups" of classes, derived these 3 abstract base classes and common services to update appropriate entities, but this part is not major now)

Also, I have the following implementations of `IEntityTypeConfiguration` interface:

```
public class RegisteredDeviceMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<RegisteredDevice>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RegisteredDevice> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(RegisteredDevice));
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        builder.Property(p => p.EldIdentifier).HasMaxLength(6).IsFixedLength();
        builder.Property(p => p.Phone).HasMaxLength(128);
        builder.Property(p => p.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

        builder.Property(p => p.AddedSyncId).HasMaxLength(64);
        builder.Property(p => p.DeletedSyncId).HasMaxLength(64);


        builder.HasOne(a => a.AddedSync)
            .WithMany(a => a.AddedDevices)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.AddedSyncId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.HasOne(a => a.DeletedSync)
            .WithMany(a => a.DeletedDevices)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.DeletedSyncId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.HasOne(a => a.Vendor)
            .WithMany(a => a.RegisteredDevices)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.VendorId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

        builder.HasOne(a => a.PreviousDevice)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<BaseDevice<RegisteredDeviceSync>>(p => p.PreviousDeviceId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}
```

(and similar for `RegisteredDeviceSync` and `RegisteredDeviceHistory`)

`DataContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<BaseDevice<BaseDeviceSync>>().UseTpcMappingStrategy();
  modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(RegisteredDeviceMap).Assembly);
}
```

but when I try to create migrations I receive:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation.  --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: A key cannot be configured on
> 'RegisteredDevice' because it is a derived type. The key must be
> configured on the root type 'BaseDevice'. If you
> did not intend for 'BaseDevice' to be included
> in the model, ensure that it is not referenced by a DbSet property on
> your context, referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder, or
> referenced from a navigation on a type that is included in the model.

on line: `builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);`

Why so and how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: Looking for [Table per Concrete Type](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines)?

Comment: Have you tried removing `builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);`. It should be discovered as primary key by convention.